# Php Result page to be displayed on same page

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, search

This is my coding for the search form:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="https://excelforth.com/search1.php" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="query" />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The thing is , When I submit this form on my web page , It goes to the php Results page and displays the results. But the thing is that it is just a plain page with just the results displayed.

My search page :

```
www.mysite/test/certification-database-search/
```

The Php file is located in my webroot folder . I was told that for wordpress , the individual subpages cannot be edited .

How do I :

1.Display the results on the same page as the search page. Not a completely new page.

2.Retain the page layout and theme / headers/ footers of the page

3.If possible run the .php file in  /certification-database-search/ and query it from there. instead of using the one in my webroot folder.

THANKS!!

Comment: Put your form and PHP in one page, PHP on top with HTML below, then use `action=""` - use the variables from the inputs as `$var=$_GET['var'];` then `echo $var;` for example (in a nutshell)

Comment: You're welcome. You can wrap your PHP inside a conditional statement, such as `if(isset($_GET['submit'])){ // code }` then name your submit button `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your form and PHP in one page, PHP on top with HTML below, then use `action=""`

Use the variables from the inputs as `$var=$_GET['var'];` then echo `$var;`

Sidenote: If you want to stop a process, you can use `die();` or `exit();`

You can put a message inside it; i.e.: `die("Enter a search term");`

**A basic example:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
$query=$_GET['query'];
echo $query;
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="query" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**An alternative**, showing an error message if field is empty:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){
  if(empty($_GET['query'])){
echo "Enter a search term";
  }

$query=$_GET['query'];
echo $query;
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Search</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="query" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```